# How to handle websocket @OnError

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, onerror

What's the correct way of handling a websocket error besides logging it?

Regarding `onError()`, the Endpoint [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Endpoint.html#onError%28javax.websocket.Session,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) states that:

> Developers may implement this method when the web socket session
> creates some kind of error that is not modeled in the web socket
> protocol. This may for example be a notification that an incoming
> message is too big to handle, or that the incoming message could not
> be encoded.
>
> There are a number of categories of exception that this method is
> (currently) defined to handle:
>
> - connection problems, for example, a socket failure that occurs before the web socket connection can be formally closed. These are modeled as SessionExceptions
> - runtime errors thrown by developer created message handlers calls.
> - conversion errors encoding incoming messages before any message handler has been called. These are modeled as DecodeExceptions

Are all of these types of exceptions fatal, causing the websocket to close?

Should the `onError()` method close the websocket (call `Session.close()`) if an error occurs?

So far, I assumed that it's my responsibility to cleanly close the session, informing the client about the close reason. This is why my `onError()` tried invoking `session.close()` if `session.isOpen()` returned true, but this caused tomcat (8.0.15) to throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:444)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:536)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:441)
    at my.package.MyEndpoint.onWebSocketError(MyEndpoint.java:229)
    ... 18 more
```

Is this a tomcat bug, a misunderstanding on my part, or both?

**Edit:** It seems that the Java EE websocket example [dukeeetf2](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/sources/svn/content/trunk/examples/web/websocket/dukeetf2/src/main/java/javaeetutorial/web/dukeetf2/ETFEndpoint.java?rev=1783) assumes that errors are fatal; and that there's no need to close the session. The errors are logged, and the session is removed:

```
@OnError
public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
    /* Remove this connection from the queue */
    queue.remove(session);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, t.toString());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection error.");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@OnError` method invocation does not mean that Session will be closed; You can do whatever you want, it depends in the contract specified by your application.

stacktrace from tomcat implementation seems like a bug.

ad [dukeeetf2](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/sources/svn/content/trunk/examples/web/websocket/dukeetf2/src/main/java/javaeetutorial/web/dukeetf2/ETFEndpoint.java?rev=1783) sample - seems like this code contains other assumptions - Endpoints does not throw an exception, so everything caught here is from underlying WebSocket framework implementation. That does not really mean that there is an "Connection Error"; I would maybe do close right away (if this is how I wan't my application to handle errors); this implementation could result in opened connections without any messages.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about the session remaining open? Is this documented someplace?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately, this info is not clearly stated anywhere, but it makes sense; `@OnClose` (or Endpoint.onClose) is required to be invoked when session is closed, so there is no point to clean any endpoint related resources before this happens. On the other hand, `@OnError` (or Endpoint.onError) is triggered anytime when there is an unhandled exception thrown from an endpoint (+Decode/EncodeExeption, ..), which can be solved by endpoint implementatiton, thus it is not necessary to close the underlying session.

Comment: That makes sense to me too, but I find the lack of documentation suspicious. The fact that this makes sense doesn't mean that this is the way this actually works.

Comment: Well ;) I remember talking about this with JSR 356 spec lead and at that time, he confirmed that this is intended behaviour. Anyway, spec explicitly mentions that `@OnClose` MUST be called when the session is closed, so performing a cleanup there cannot be wrong. (You might need to do additional checks in `@OnError`, since it can be called after `@OnClose` - for example when `@OnClose` throws an exception).

Comment: I read the code of Undertow (the JBoss impl of Websockets) myself and saw that this is the case. `onError` doesn't call `onClose` implicitly. `onError` is called whenever there is an unhandled exception thrown by other `on*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this is a bit dated but ended up here today when looking for this info.
Depending on how you rely on the state of the websocket, you need to close the session manually, at least for the javax.websocket implementation.

In my case, the error happening was causing a problem for the websession client administration implementation, so I closed the session as in the above example.
I think it depends on what you need, but it certainly does not do a close session in this implementation.